# Laravel 5 Async Database Transaction?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Odd issue here, I have a view `content.home` that relies on the authenticated user's `User` model to resolve and be passed to it.

Before the User model is ready, I have a simple function in which I pass a name to the authenticated user's `User` model.

That code is below, including the view return:

```
    public function name()
    {
    $input = Input::all();
    $name = $input['name'];
    if(strlen($name)>2) //some validation
    {
    $user = User::where('id',Auth::id())->first();
    $user->name = $name;
    $user->save();
    return view('content.home')->with('user', Auth::user());        
    }
    }
```

My problem is, when I return the view I don't have the user's `name`. As soon as I refresh the page, it appears. Other user data provided by `Auth::user()` is there, but not the name. How can that be when I just saved it? It isn't `NULL`, again if I refresh the page right away it shows up.

I'm getting the `name` in the blade view like so:

```
{{$user->name}}
```

Is `save()` async? I don't think so. Is there some latency?

How can I make sure that the model being passed is properly resolved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in case someone has a similar issue:

The reason this failed without a refresh is that there is some kind of cache on `Auth::user()`.

When I pass the `$user` I saved to rather than the `Auth::user()`, even though it is the same user, it works.

So change `return view('content.home')->with('user', Auth::user());`

to

```
return view('content.home')->with('user', $user);
```

Comment: The reason you had this problem is because your User instance from the query is a completely different instance than what Auth::user() is referencing.

Comment: @jjones Why do you say that? Are they not (in this case) referencing the same user?

Comment: They are the same user, but are not the same instance of the User class. When you update the name of the User instance returned by the query, the instance referenced by Auth::user() will not be effected because it is a different instance of the User class.